# How to solve the heat PDE with a dirac delta in the boundary condition?`

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dirac-delta

Consider the standard 1D non-dimensionalized heat equation,
$$u_t = u_{xx}$$
subject to:
$$u(x=0,t)=\delta(t), u(x=1,t)=1, u(x,0)=f(x)$$

The way I decided to break the problem down was by splitting it up into two parts.
So, $$u = v+w$$
Where,
$$v(x=0,t)=0, v(x=1,t)=1, v(x,0)=f(x)$$ and
$$w(x=0,t)=\delta (t), w(x=1,t)=0, w(x,0) = 0$$

I can solve the PDE for $v$ using the steady-state solution and so on, but how do I resolve the dirac delta distribution showing up in my problem?

Comment: Interpret $\delta$ as the weak limit of a sequence of approximation to the identity (nascent delta functions), such as $\eta_\epsilon=\epsilon^{-1}1_{[0,\epsilon]}$ and solve?

Comment: The resp. roles of $x$ vs. $t$ look to me as if they were inverted: usually, we have a $\delta$ at time $t=0$ and we "see/impose" what happens at time $t=1$... But maybe I am wrong...

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): The given boundary conditions at the corner $(x,t)=(0,0)$ seem mutually inconsistent.